# Php, url из файла?

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы pinS Брались из файла (**urls.txt**)?
В php не очень, но вот этот код не работает.

```
$pinS = (file("urls.txt")); - нужно сделать
```

Нужно чтобы ссылки брали из файла...

```
 pinS("http://site.com/sitemap.xml"); - нужно убрать
 pinS("http://site2.com/sitemap.xml"); - нужно убрать

function pinS($url)
```

Comment: @wpseo, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.